# How to Disable button using javascript or jquery inside PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to invisible all buttons when the table column `selection` value is not `none`. Then how to Disable button using javascript or jquery inside PHP code. suggestions are welcome to do this task using php code inside  javascript or jquery.I have buttons list as follows.

```
<?php include("db_conection.php");$sql = "SELECT selection FROM users";
$result = $dbcon->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$value = $row['selection']; 
if($value !='none'){
//need to add jquery or javascript here 
//$('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
//$('button').text('Disabled');    
}
}
}?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
  // $('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
  // $('button').text('Disabled');  
  < /script>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="q1-1">Q1-1</button >
  < /td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="q2-1">Q2-1</button >
  < /td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="q3-1">Q3-1</button >
  < /td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="q4-1">Q4-1</button >
  < /td>
    </tr >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the value first in a **Text Element**:

```
<input type"text" id="sampleValue" value="<?php echo($value)> // this will put the value in a text element.
```

After that, you use it in JQuery by its ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   if($('#sampleValue')!='none') {
      $('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('button').text('Disabled');
   }
</script>
```